# How to share image dynamically by url on a Viewpager android

Tags: android, facebook

How can i pass the assigned url of the images once share it in facebook? i got 3 images on the viewpager. so every image can share it in facebook using share button

heres my MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShare;


ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;


int[] bookCover = new int[] { 

        R.drawable.image1, 
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, 

    };

//for image1 - the url is http;//image1.com 
//for image2 - the url is http;//image2.com 
//for image3 - the url is http;//image3.com 


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupFacebookConnect(savedInstanceState);


     if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
     }


     btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);


     btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            shareImage(string url);
        }
    });



        // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, bookCover);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
             // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
             // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
             // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

        });



    public void shareImage(string url) {
         Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            params.putString("picture", imageFromURL);

            WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                    "Publish cancelled", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
                                "Publish cancelled", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Error posting story", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }



                })
                .build();
            feedDialog.show();

    }
```

and heres my page adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;

int[] bookCover;
LayoutInflater inflater;

Button share;


private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] bookCover) {
    this.context = context;
    this.bookCover = bookCover;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bookCover.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {


    final PdfHandler pdf = new PdfHandler(context);
    final int pdfPos = position;



    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

    ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    //imgflag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imgflag.setImageResource(bookCover[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViefeewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    imgflag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.setEnabled(false);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pdfPos == 0) {

                pdf.openPdf("pdf");     

            } 

            if(pdfPos == 1) {

                pdf.openPdf("pdf");
            } 

            if(pdfPos == 2) {   

                pdf.openPdf("pdf");                             
            } 



        }


    });

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?? pls tell